# How to evaluate a System.Linq.Expressions.Expression

Tags: c#, .net

What is the correct or robust way to evaluate a `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` to obtain a value (object)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm tentatively using the following, but don't know if it's the preferred method:

```
public static object Evaluate(Expression e)
{
    //A little optimization for constant expressions
    if (e.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
        return ((ConstantExpression)e).Value;
    return Expression.Lambda(e).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
}
```

Comment: What if the expression is a parameterized lambda expression?

Comment: Good question... In my use case, I shouldn't ever get a lambda expression, parameterized or not. (I'll add a check for that.)

Answer (score 3):

Timothy Shields answer is correct for when there are no parameters.
For parameterized expressions, you can use an overload of `Expression.Lambda` (the method used in his code) that takes a collection of `ParameterExpression`, but the `ParameterExpression` values have to be the same instances as those used in the given `Expression`. If it is a sub-expression of a parameterized expression using parameters from the root expression, you can get the parameters from it (pass `LambdaExpression.Parameters` from the root to `Expression.Lambda`).

(If your expression is already a `LambdaExpression`, you can just cast to it and call `Compile`.)

Then pass your parameters to `DynamicInvoke(...)`.

---

Here's a method, extending Timothy Shields method, for invoking a sub-expression when you have the root expression.
The root expression must be `LamdbaExpression` (or a subclass such as `Expression<TDelegate>`.)

Since we don't know which parameters of the root expression are required by the sub-expression, we pass all of them. (If you know this in your case, you can adapt this code.)

This doesn't handle all cases.
It doesn't let you get the values of `out` or reference parameters, and there are probably other unsupported cases.

If your expression is not a sub-expression or you don't have the root `Expression`, you'll have to get the `ParameterExpression`s some other way.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace LinqTest
{
    public class LinqCompileSubExpression
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Compile and invoke a sub-expression of a <see cref="LambdaExpression"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rootExpression">A parameterised expression.</param>
        /// <param name="subExpression">An sub-expression or <paramref name="rootExpression"/>.</param>
        /// <param name="arguments">
        /// The arguments to be supplied on invoking. These must match the parameters to the root expression (empty if it has no parameters).
        /// Any parameters not used by the sub-expression are ignored.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>The return value of the sub-expression.</returns>
        /// <typeparam name="TReturn">The type of the return value. Use <see cref="Object"/> if it is not known.</typeparam>
        /// <remarks>
        /// If invoking the same expression multiple times, use <see cref="CompileSubExpression(LambdaExpression, Expression)"/> once,
        /// then invoke the delegate (for efficiency).
        /// </remarks>
        public static TReturn InvokeSubExpression<TReturn>(LambdaExpression rootExpression, Expression subExpression, params object[] arguments)
        {
            // compile it (to a delegate):
            Delegate compiledDelegate = CompileSubExpression(rootExpression, subExpression);

            // invoke the delegate:
            return (TReturn)compiledDelegate.DynamicInvoke(arguments);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compile a sub-expression of a <see cref="LambdaExpression"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rootExpression">A parameterised expression.</param>
        /// <param name="subExpression">An sub-expression or <paramref name="rootExpression"/>.</param>
        /// <returns>The compiled expression.</returns>
        public static Delegate CompileSubExpression(LambdaExpression rootExpression, Expression subExpression)
        {
            // convert the sub-expression to a LambdaExpression with the same parameters as the root expression:
            LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(subExpression, rootExpression.Parameters);

            // compile it (to a delegate):
            return lambda.Compile();
        }
    }
}
```

These are unit tests using the Microsoft test framework.
The actual code required is three lines in the two static methods above.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using static LinqTest.LinqCompileSubExpression;

namespace LinqTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class LinqCompileSubExpressionTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void InvokeExpressionTest1()
        {
            Expression<Func<string, int>> rootExpression = s => s.Substring(4).Length;

            var subExpression = ((MemberExpression)rootExpression.Body).Expression;   // just the `s.Substring(4)` part
            Assert.AreEqual("t string", InvokeSubExpression<string>(rootExpression, subExpression, "input string"));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void InvokeExpressionTest2()
        {
            Expression<Func<object, int>> rootExpression = x => x.ToString().Length;

            var subExpression = ((MemberExpression)rootExpression.Body).Expression;   // just the `x.ToString()` part
            Assert.AreEqual("5", InvokeSubExpression<string>(rootExpression, subExpression, 5));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void InvokeExpressionTest3()
        {
            Expression<Func<ClassForTest, int>> rootExpression = x => x.StrProperty.Length + 15;

            var subExpression = ((BinaryExpression)rootExpression.Body).Right;   // `15`
            Assert.AreEqual(15, InvokeSubExpression<int>(rootExpression, subExpression, new ClassForTest()));  // argument is irrelevant
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void InvokeExpressionTest4()
        {
            Expression<Func<int, int>> rootExpression = x => Math.Abs(x) + ClassForTest.GetLength(x.ToString());

            var subExpression = ((BinaryExpression)rootExpression.Body).Right;
            Assert.AreEqual(3, InvokeSubExpression<int>(rootExpression, subExpression, 123));   // we pass root parameter but evaluate the sub-expression only
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void InvokeExpressionTest5()
        {
            Expression<Func<int, int>> rootExpression = x => ClassForTest.GetLength(x.ToString());

            var subExpression = ((MethodCallExpression)rootExpression.Body).Arguments[0];        // just the `x.ToString()` part
            Assert.AreEqual("123", InvokeSubExpression<string>(rootExpression, subExpression, 123));  // we pass root parameter but evaluate the sub-expression only
        }

        public class ClassForTest
        {
            public string StrProperty { get; set; }
            public static int GetLength(string s) => s.Length;
        }
    }
}
```